# every time i have reference to MyObjectBox or Entiry_ class build fails

Tags: objectbox

im trying to migrate to objectbox iv build an example 
iv configured gradle with all needed
project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.object_box_version = '1.0.1'
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$object_box_version"
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
        }
    }
}
```

app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'

dependencies {
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$object_box_version"
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-kotlin:$object_box_version"
    kapt "io.objectbox:objectbox-processor:$object_box_version"
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
class User(
        @Id
        var id: Long = 0,
        var name: String = ""
)
```

than when i create my App class to build BoxStore i find MyObjectBox but after i have references of it in my code and i hit rebuild i get error cant find MyObjectBox ( or any other ObjectBox generated class like Entity_ .. )

Comment: Don't spot anything obvious here. So I have a couple of questions for you: 1) Are you seeing any errors in the build? Anything else that might be related to ObjectBox? 2) What the order of your "apply plugin" commands? 3) Did you check if https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-examples/tree/master/objectbox-kotlin-example works for you? If so, what's the difference compared to your project?

Comment: hi
1) no errors or warnings
2) i tried 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
and 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'

3) i haven't tried the sample but ill try it now

i uninstalled android studio and the sdk and reinstalled nothing changed..

Answer (score 1):

all i was missing was

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```